# hive How to use conditional statements to execute different query based on result

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, hive, hiveql

I have query `select col1, col2 from view1` and I wanted execute only when `(select columnvalue from table1) > 0` else do nothing.

```
if (select columnvalue from table1)>0 
                   select col1, col2 from view1" 
                  else 
                      do thing
```

How can I achieve this in single hive query?

Comment: the question is about Spark or Hive?

Answer (score 0):

If check query returns scalar value (single row) then you can cross join with check result and filter using > 0 condition:

```
 with check_query as (
 select count (*) cnt 
 from table1
 )

 select *   
 from view1 t
      cross join check_query c
  where c.cnt>0
 ;
```